# Energy level/shell version of the conduction band in a solid?

Tags: electrons, quantum-information

As far as I know, the isolated version of the valence band is the valence shell, so the isolated version of the conduction band should be conduction shell?

As electrons in a lattice that are exposed to heat/light become excited and therefore jump to the conduction band from the valence band, which allows them to move throughout the solid. However, what happens on an isolated scale is where I'm confused.

Comment: Not sure to have catch your question correctly but perhaps you can find something related in https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/88690/48509 my answer.  The bands I refer to includes hopping of charges.

Comment: Thanks, dude. It helped me get a little bit better idea

Comment: Not sure if it fits . But surely it fits with the conduction that we have in amorphous semiconductors and even powderised cupper.

Comment: Not sure if it fits . But surely it fits with the conduction that we have in amorphous semiconductors and even powderised cupper.